# What is the default file path location for BufferTempStoragePath in SSIS 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am receiving the following error:

> The buffer manager cannot create a temporary storage file on any path
>   in the BufferTempStoragePath property. There is an incorrect file name
>   or no permission.

Has anyone ever seen this?  Permissions are fine, might be a disk space issue, but I can't find the path that it is talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default, the directory specified by the TEMP environment variable
>   is used

- The above quote http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.mainpipeclass.buffertempstoragepath.aspx
- More details about what the BufferTempStoragePath is used for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141031.aspx
- A post on why you should override that value, even if you don't anticipate needing it http://www.bimonkey.com/2008/04/blobtempstoragepath-and-buffertempstoragepath/

Answer (score 2):

Find some helpful information here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/f5d6c64a-c275-401e-93e6-2abfd936e7a1/