# SSIS XML Source String DataType Length Error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I've a XML Source column "Comments" and data type is UniCode WSTR but in the source [UI] its capturing more than 4000 characters so SSIS ETL failed to load in destination table as the error shows "truncation of data length" & Destination column DataType is nVarchar(Max).
Please suggest me how to load the data into destination.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare this column as an **NTEXT**. However, beware of two downsides of such step:

- You have to check this definition **every time** you update XML datasource Yes, every time, because SSIS likes to reset string XML elements to its default - nvarchar(50).
- Using **NTEXT** column has a negative performance impact, for details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28507399